# Fixed outer container with scrollable inner container

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Intended outcome: Allow for inner container to be scrolled as content populates the div. Outer container should not scroll, only inner container.

I have a box with a dropdown where users can make a selection and then see an answer get 'typed' out inside the box depending on which selection was clicked. The answer in the inner container overflows due to the amount of text. We want to allow for the inner content container to be scrollable, while keeping the outer container with the dropdown and selected question to stay fixed, with no scrolling.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
export function typingDemo() {
return (
<div className="demo__wrapper">
    <Title />
    <DropdownMenu />
    <div className="demo__content--container">
        <Content />
    </div>
</div>
);
}
```

Relevant CSS

```
.demo__wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50vh;
}

.demo__content--container {
    overflow-y: auto; //also tried 'scroll' here
    min-height: 75%;
}
```

My initial idea was to set the overflow-y of the demo__wrapper container to hidden and the overflow-y of the demo__content--container to 'auto' or 'scroll'. This fits the requirement of the outer container not being scrollable, but the content in the inner div is inaccessible.

Basically, I want the demo__wrapper to not move when scrolling, while allowing for the demo__content--container to be scrolled when it overflows. Inner container should always be the same size (accomplished this by setting the height of the inner container).

Comment: I think you could make the main content scroll and just set a fixed sort-of window that gives the sensation of not scrolling. I apologize if I didn't understand what you actually wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Change the inner div's `min-height` to `height` or set a `max-height`.

The problem is that you've set a `min-height` on the inner div but not a `height` or `max-height`. That makes the inner div grow according to its content, even beyond the fixed height of the outer div. That overflow is hidden. The `overflow: scroll;` or `overflow: auto;` of the inner div never comes into play.